# Spring Boot 2.3.2 default security

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I am using Spring Security for basic authentication. But it comes with default authentication.I am trying to disable it, disabling it through application.properties. This is what I tried:

SpringBasicSecurityApplication.java

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude={SecurityAutoConfiguration.class})
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SpringBasicSecurityApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBasicSecurityApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

ApplicationController.java

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/rest/auth")
public class ApplicationController {
      @GetMapping("/getMsg")
      public String greeting() {
            return "Spring Security Example!!!";
      }
}
```

application.properties

```
spring.security.user.name=xusername
spring.security.user.passward=xpassword
server.port = 8081
logging.level.org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security=INFO
```

[image: What ever I type localhost:8081 or localhost:8081/rest/auth/getMsg this login page will open]

[image: after using username as xusername and password as xpassword the this happen]

what am i doing wrong? thanks in advance.

Comment: `passward`? you havn't disabled anything... you have only set a username and password.. and you have misspelled it, thats not disabling...

Comment: What do you mean by *I am trying to disable it,*? Do you want no authentication at all or do you want only HTTP Basic authentication? I can't see that you disabled anything? What line should that do?

Comment: @ThomasAndolf, sorry its a typo mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just give everyone permission to any request in config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    // HTTP security configuration
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .requestMatchers(PathRequest.toStaticResources().atCommonLocations()).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().permitAll
                .and().httpBasic();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you @Seldo97 for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Seldo97 you suggestion work for me but I want to give authentication for some special kind of URL so with help of your code I did like:-

```
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("admin").password("admin").roles("ADMIN");
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("user").roles("USER");
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable();
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/resto/**").hasRole("ADMIN").anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated().and()
            .httpBasic();

`@Bean
public static NoOpPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return (NoOpPasswordEncoder) NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
}`
```

Thank you for your help :)